# Why am I getting an SSH error when trying to clone a Github Repository?

Tags: macos, github, ssh

When I am trying to clone a Github Repo to my desktop using SSH, I am getting the following error

```
Cloning into 'prework-about-me'...
/Users/eugeneho/.ssh/config line 4: garbage at end of line; ".ssh/id_rsa".
/Users/eugeneho/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here is what my config file looks like

```
eugeneho@Eugenes-MacBook-Pro .ssh % cat config
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/ .ssh/id_rsa
```

This is what my id_rsa file looks like

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
(my key is here)
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is my file structure
[image: File structure]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an unnecessary space in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
IdentityFile ~/ .ssh/id_rsa
               ^
```

Comment: How do you remove the unnecessary space in the ~/.ssh/config file?

I didn't manage to google my way to the answer.

Comment: @SebastiantenBerge The same you remove any symbol in a text file; with a text editor and your computers backspace or del key. Are you sure you have the exact same error message?